# Grails global repository credentials

Tags: grails, grails-3.0, grails-3.1

Does anybody know how to specify credentials for custom repository in USER_HOME/.grails/settings.groovy file?

Currently it looks like:

```
grails {
  profiles {
    repositories {
      myRepo {
        url = "http://foo.com/repo"
        snapshotsEnabled = true
      }
      grailsCentral {
        url = "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
        snapshotsEnabled = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But there is no docs on how to specify username/password for "myRepo".

I'm using Grails 3.

Answer (score 0):

Grails 3 uses [Gradle](http://gradle.org/videos/leveraging-gradle-in-grails-3-0/) for the build. The build configuration details are stored in build.gradle. You can insert in credentials to access a repository in this file. See example below:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "url to repo"
        credentials {
            username = "username"
            password = "password"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's ok, but I mean the case when you create a new application with custom profile which is located in private repository. So, at this point there is no project and, hence, no build.gradle available.